# Unable to Rotate log file on Wildfly 10.1.0

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, wildfly, wildfly-10

I want to rotate log file in every hour so it will create 24 files in one day and next day 24 and so on
So i have created a custom handler as below

```
<custom-handler name="filehandler" class="org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler" module="org.jboss.logmanager">
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <properties>
        <property name="maxBackupIndex" value="24"/>
        <property name="rotateSize" value="10000"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
        <property name="append" value="true"/>
        <property name="fileName" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
    </properties>
</custom-handler>
```

But it gives me below error. I am using windows 64 bit. 
In Wildfly 10.1.0 it had jboss-logmanager-2.0.4.Final.jar and in some forum I read to downgradee the jar to jboss-logmanager-2.0.3.Final.jar but after downgrading it keeps writing to the same log file.

```
[Server:server-one] LogManager error of type OPEN_FAILURE: Unable to rotate log file
[Server:server-one] java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\wildfly10_slave1\domain\servers\server-one\log\server.log -> D:\wildfly10_slave1\domain\servers\server-one\log\server.log
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
[Server:server-one]
[Server:server-one]     at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
[Server:server-one]     at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler.rotate(PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler.java:251)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler.preWrite(PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler.java:232)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.doPublish(WriterHandler.java:60)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:76)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:314)
[Server:server-one] 16:49:57,739 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:322)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:322)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:322)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.logRaw(Logger.java:850)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.logRaw(Logger.java:860)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.log(Logger.java:393)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.log.JDKModuleLogger.doLog(JDKModuleLogger.java:105)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.log.JDKModuleLogger.doLog(JDKModuleLogger.java:97)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.log.JDKModuleLogger.greeting(JDKModuleLogger.java:178)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Module.setModuleLogger(Module.java:970)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:483)
```

Update :

There is already an issue reported in JIRA
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/LOGMGR-154
I tried with the latest jboss-log manager but it did not work and also 2.0.8-Final jar does not exist

Comment: Check who is blocking your logs files, Eg. with https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-find-out-which-c0d4e60e

Comment: @FedericoSierra I tried to check with the given command, It does not show it is locked by some program.

Comment: Somewhat of a guess, but if you have a anti-virus running it could be that.